# android listview each row has a checkbox

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to build an listview and each row has a checkbox with image and textview, i almost made it, but when i put the checkbox i can't press the list_row, i mean before i put the checkbox i can click the row and it hover as i did in my style, but after i put the checkbox when i click on the list_row it didn't hover and the onitemclick doesn't work, why ?

this is the xml of my each list_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/restaurant_list_item_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left sied Thumbnail image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/restaurant_list_item_image_bg"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/restaurant_multi_select_list_item_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/rihanna" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_multi_select_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <!-- Rightend check box -->

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/restaurant_multi_select_checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
        android:checked="false"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding focusable elements (like CheckBox or Button) disables the ability to click the overall list item and their focusability has to be disabled.

Add the following in your checkbox attributes in the xml and then try

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" could also be used in the parent RelativeLayout. Good answer.

Comment: yes it works , the hover works again , but now when i click on any list_row item the first check box select , why?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is exactly. You might to want to check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294174/android-listview-of-checkboxes-always-checks-first-item-if-any-item-is-checked

Comment: I have written a small example here on github. Check it out just in case https://github.com/asabbarwal/CustomListViewWithCheckboxes

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeRoy : Thank you very much. That was some new information. I will try it out. :)

Comment: @AbhishekSabbarwal i see every example about customize listview has implement its own arrayadapter class, i didn't , i make like this `SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), listRestaurants,
    R.layout.restaurant_multi_select_list_item, from, to);` is this wrong ? (i am new to android_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23154/discussion-between-abhishek-sabbarwal-and-fernado-margin)

Answer (score 1):

yeah because checkbox presence makes the view unclickable.You need to implement onClicklistenrs of both ImageView and TextView you are using and write same code on thier click as you wanted on list row click

Setting focus will help only with touching but checkbox click will be implemented as well

Comment: i got you, but i didn't write a onclicklistener, i make it on xml style, so what should i do now ?